# Responding With custom code in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

I am creating a web Server using spring boot. Now In Response, I want to send my Status Code when some api hits the server.I want to create my own Status code . Like instead of Sending 401 , I want to send 421.

Response.status(421)
Something like this.

Comment: I want to send status code which are not predefined, like 421, its not predefined

Comment: It's answered in the linked question as well.

Comment: They are sending predefined codes ,not custom codes.

Comment: Read and try the answers. The accepted answer uses a named int constant in second snippet.

Comment: All the libraries that are used for sending Status : HttpStatus or HttpServletResponse , they have inbuilt predefined status.We cant create our own

Comment: That's a new one. What about this [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus(int)) then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<String> someTest() {
   return ResponseEntity
      .status(421)
      .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      .body("go away world");
}
```

Testing...

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:8080/test
HTTP/1.1 421
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 11
Date: Tue, 03 Sep 2019 12:23:58 GMT
```